# Why are values not getting passed between arguments?

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to pass a value from one fragment to another. But I am always getting the values as null in the other fragment. My codes are as below.Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

senttask.java

```
          String p1=tname.getText().toString();
          Fragment fr;
          fr=new TaskSentFragment();
          FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
          android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putString("CID ", p1);
          Log.i("cid",""+p1);

          fr.setArguments(args);
          ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);

                   ft.commit();
```

taskSentFragment.java

```
      String id=getArguments().getString("CID");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args.putString("CID ", p1);` key is `CID`

This

```
String id=getArguments().getString("p1");
```

Should be

```
String id=getArguments().getString("CID");
```

Edit :

> I am trying to pass a value from one fragment to another

I din't notice its Fragment to Fragment Communication.

You need to use interface as a call back to the activity. Then communicate value to other fragment

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Quoting docs

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.